# How to remove/hide Headless Chrome printouts Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I'm using the headless chrome driver; however using it creates some printouts:

```
[0705/220956.206:INFO:CONSOLE(66)] "visitorResponseData set", source: https://eastprodcdn.azureedge.net/bundles/legacy/velaro.inline.9b226ddb.js (66)
[0705/220958.919:INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Hotjar not launching due to suspicious userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36", source: https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-1144113.js?sv=6 (3)
[0705/220959.529:INFO:CONSOLE(66)] "visitorResponseData set", source: https://eastprodcdn.azureedge.net/bundles/legacy/velaro.inline.9b226ddb.js (66)
[0705/221012.837:INFO:CONSOLE(66)] "visitorResponseData set", source: https://eastprodcdn.azureedge.net/bundles/legacy/velaro.inline.9b226ddb.js (66)
```

Is there any way to remove/hide them? These are from the headless option, not from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `options.add_argument('log-level=3')` as an option in the same way you added the headless. You can choose between different log levels, it should solve your problem.